# Unable to perform regression on CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm using Keras to build a a convolutional neural network which takes images with the shape `(200, 200, 3)` and should output a number representing the predicted amount of likes this image would get on social media. y_train and y_test are dimensional vectors. Here is my code so far:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(10, 1, 1, input_shape=(200, 200, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(10, 1, 1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
# model.add(Flatten())

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

I'm getting an error saying

> expected activation_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape
>   (7, 1)

Where (7, 1) is the shape of `y_train`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Run `model.summary()` to see the shapes of each layer. `y_train` should have a shape like the last layer (without considering the batch dimension, of course).

Comment: @today it says the shape of all the layers is `(None, 200, 200, 10)`

Comment: ..which is a 4 dimensional tensor, just as the error is telling you. Your layers are obviously not resulting in your desired prediction shape.

Comment: @Konstantinoskokos I know. But I dont know why, which is literally why I asked.

Comment: Since you are using `MaxPool2D` as the last layer (with a default window size of `2*2`), you end up with an output tensor of shape `(100, 100, 10)`. On the other hand you are trying to predict one single value. Therefore, the last layer should have a shape of `(1,)`. One way to achieving this is using a `Flatten` layer followed by a `Dense` layer with as single unit as the last layer. However, as last layer is huge (i.e. `100*100*10`), it might be better to use a few more conv and pooling layers to reduce the size of tensors and then use a `Dense` layer at the end. Cont in the next comment...

Comment: His output values are actually 7-dimensional (one-hot categorical) though

Comment: Cont: I guess you are new to Keras and Convolutional Networks. If that's the case, then I highly recommend to read these [tutorials/notebooks](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks) written by the creator of Keras, François Chollet, to learn more about convolutional networks as well as Keras. For you, I specifically recommend these two: [1](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/3.7-predicting-house-prices.ipynb) and [2](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.1-introduction-to-convnets.ipynb).

Comment: One important point: don't use convolutions with a kernel size of `1*1`. The minimum recommended size is `3*3` (`1*1` convolutions have another applications and are rarely used alone).

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are using a fixed size input images, you can add fully connected layers
2. Categorical cross entropy is a function to compare probabilistic distributions (i.e.for classification problems not regression), you can use Mean Squared Error loss function instead.

Here is a sample code:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(10, 1, 1, input_shape=(200, 200, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(10, 1, 1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))  
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
test_mse = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test) 
print('test set mse is {}'.format(test_mse))
```

Comment: At 10 epochs this gives a MSE of around 2260.

Comment: The code shows how you can have a working model while tweaking the model to get a better result is up to you. MSE value is dependent on labels values of your training set.

Comment: How would you change the model so that rather than regression, it predicts which image is "better" (ie having the bigger number in `y_train`)?  Will you need to take every two consecutive images and compare them together and keep doing this with the results?